# jQuery button not displaying properly

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using a jQuery button in my application, but for some reason the it is displaying as a normal button without the jQuery properties. The html markup is inside a separate file called `ajax.php`, and the jQuery is in the main file.

Here is the coding for the jQuery:

```
$(".back_to_list").button().live("click", function(){
});
```

Here is the html markup for the button:

```
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<table>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="back_to_list" >Back</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>';

echo $html;
```

Does anyone know why the button is not displaying as a jQuery ui button?

Comment: `.button()` is from `jQueryUI` which is not part of the `jQuery Core`.

Comment: Note that [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is **deprecated in 1.7, and removed in 1.9 JQuery version**.

Comment: @Vucko, this has been noted, version 1.7 is in use for this particular application

Comment: Do you have jQuery ui plugin below jquery lib?

Comment: I have used the jQuery button in other places, they all work, but for some reason this one stays the same

Comment: Also, check your javascript error log. Maybe another (totally not related) issue is 'stopping' javascript parsing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you call your .button() code (as in your first sample) when the document is loaded:

```
$(function () { // jQuery "wrapper" for 'run when document is loaded
    $(".back_to_list").button().live("click", function(){
    });
});
```

**Edit:** also note that [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, **and removed as of jQuery 1.9** Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). That could also be your problem if you are running a newer version of jQuery.